# Why, in Ubuntu, I cant access to an SD card using the laptop SD card reader?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-12.04, sd-card

I have ab Ubuntu 12.04 installation on a Virtual Machine and I am finding some problems try to read an SD card inserted into the SD card reader of my laptop.

The problem is that if I try to insert the SD card into the laptop reader I can't see it into the "computer resources".

I have also try to insert it and then launch the **dmesg** command to show the content of the **dmseg log** to see what happens with the driver...but I obtain this result:

```
[   56.473726] acpiphp: Slot [63] registered
[   62.134056] init: vmware-tools pre-start process (1193) terminated with status 1
[  223.200938] sda1: WRITE SAME failed. Manually zeroing.
[ 1008.130825] audit_printk_skb: 9 callbacks suppressed
[ 1008.130835] type=1400 audit(1401053536.366:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1099 comm="cupsd" pid=1099 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[ 1783.188040] psmouse serio1: Wheel Mouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
[ 1783.924612] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:/dev$
```

It seems to me that it can't see the SD reader...why? what can I do to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: What virtualization are you using? Have you configured it to pass the card reader through to the VM?

Comment: I am using VmWare WorkStation, what can I do to pass the card reader to the VM?

Comment: Yes, check to see if your virtualization software is making your VM guest aware of the host hardware. Check your VmWare application settings for anything like USB and other device settings